# Problem with add method vector of 2D-array in java

Tags: java, vector

I have declared a vector of 2D-array in java. At each step I add an array into vector by add() method. But when print out this vector to see what inside, I've got an unexpected output. None of these arrays is the data was added.
My code:

```
    static Vector<int[][]> latinSquare;
    static int[][] square;
    static int[][] maskRow, maskCol;

    static int[] extractCoor(int x, int n) {
        int[] ans = new int[2];
        ans[0] = x / n;
        ans[1] = x % n;
        return ans;
    }

    static void backtrack(int pos, int n) {
        int[] coor = extractCoor(pos, n);
        int x = coor[0], y = coor[1];

        for (int candidate = 0; candidate < n; candidate++) {
            if (maskRow[x][candidate] == 0 && maskCol[y][candidate] == 0) {
                square[x][y] = candidate;

                if (pos == n * n - 1) {
                    latinSquare.add(square);
                    printArr(square, n, n);
                } else {
                    maskRow[x][candidate] = 1;
                    maskCol[y][candidate] = 1;
                    backtrack(pos + 1, n);
                    maskRow[x][candidate] = 0;
                    maskCol[y][candidate] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I print out the `square`, I've got the correct list of latin square size n = 3.

```
0 1 2 
1 2 0 
2 0 1 

0 1 2 
2 0 1 
1 2 0 

0 2 1 
1 0 2 
2 1 0 

0 2 1 
2 1 0 
1 0 2 

1 0 2 
0 2 1 
2 1 0 

1 0 2 
2 1 0 
0 2 1 

1 2 0 
0 1 2 
2 0 1 

1 2 0 
2 0 1 
0 1 2 

2 0 1 
0 1 2 
1 2 0 

2 0 1 
1 2 0 
0 1 2 

2 1 0 
0 2 1 
1 0 2 

2 1 0 
1 0 2 
0 2 1
```

But when I print out the vector `latinSquare`, I've got wrong output:

```
    static void latinSquareBuilder(int n) {
        latinSquare = new Vector<int[][]>();
        maskRow = new int[n][n];
        maskCol = new int[n][n];
        square = new int[n][n];

        backtrack(0, n);

        for (int i = 0; i < latinSquare.size(); i++)
            printArr(latinSquare.get(i), n, n);
    }

    static void printArr(int[][] arr, int n, int m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                System.err.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.err.println();
        }
        System.err.println();
    }
```

Output:

```
2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1 

2 1 0 
1 2 2 
0 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the square is a matrix and the latinSquare is a vector. Have a look [here](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/multiplying-vector-by-a-matrix)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I just use Vector built-in library of java to store a list of 2D-array, I don't perform any mathematical operations with this data.

Comment: Try this way  latinSquare = new Vector<int>[][] ();